# python tkinter try to simplify the label things

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

so im trying to make the label things much simpler, but i can't find any way to do that

[Im trying to make it look like this but with just one Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcUuv.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import date
import lib

detect_date = date.today()
hari = detect_date.strftime("%A")

myWindow = Tk()
myWindow.title("Jadwal Kuliah")

def main():
    if (hari == "Monday"):
        Label(myWindow, text=lib.list_hari[0], font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text=lib.list_mapel[0] + "|" + lib.list_waktu[0] + "|" + lib.list_kelas[1], font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text=lib.list_dosen[0], font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="--------------------------------------------", font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text=lib.list_mapel[1] + "|" + lib.list_waktu[1] + "|" + lib.list_kelas[0], font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text=lib.list_dosen[1], font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text="--------------------------------------------", font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text=lib.list_mapel[2] + "|" + lib.list_waktu[2] + "|" + lib.list_kelas[9], font="none 14").pack()
        Label(myWindow, text=lib.list_dosen[2], font="none 14").pack()

Label(myWindow, text="JADWAL HARI INI", font="none 16", relief="sunken").pack()
main()
```

Comment: You can try using new line `\n` in the same label, like `Label(myWindow, text="{}\n{}".format(lib.list_hari[0], lib.list_mapel[0]), font="none 14").pack()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I like to do is make buttons, labels or really anything I want in semi-uniform into functions to return that object to me with pre-set settings. Example:

```
def my_label(frame, text):
    the_label = tkinter.Label(frame, text=text, font='none 14', fg='red')
    return the_label


first_label = my_label(myWindow, 'Some text here')
second_label = my_label(myWindow, 'Some other text here')
```

will return labels with those font and color settings etc. Keeping them standard.

currently though, from the image you linked it looks like your using multiple labels to populate an entire page for a condition at a time. What I would use to clean that up is use the tkinter.Text() method, this will allow you to make a good size box that you can populate instead. With using the Text() method you could...

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import date
import lib

detect_date = date.today()
hari = detect_date.strftime("%A")

myWindow = Tk()
myWindow.title("Jadwal Kuliah")

def return_text_object(frame, text):
    text_object = Text(frame, font='none 14', fg='black')
    text_object.insert(text)
    return text_object

def main():
    if (hari == "Monday"):
        data_to_display = f'{text=lib.list_hari[0]}\n{lib.list_mapel[0]}|lib.list_waktu[0]}|{lib.list_kelas[1]}\n{lib.list_dosen[0]}\n--------------------------------------------\n{lib.list_mapel[1]}|{lib.list_waktu[1]}|{lib.list_kelas[0]}\n{lib.list_dosen[1]}\n--------------------------------------------\n{lib.list_mapel[2]}|{lib.list_waktu[2]}|{lib.list_kelas[9]}\n{lib.list_dosen[2]}'

        text_output = return_text_object(myWindow,data_to_display)
        text_output.pack()

Label(myWindow, text="JADWAL HARI INI", font="none 16", relief="sunken").pack()
main()
```